# Reflectance sensor circuit

Tags: arduino

i'm a grade 9 student and a beginner at Arduino. I'm working alone on a robotics project. I am working on a Poulo QTR-1A Reflectance sensor and I was wondering what this symbol represents.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: that is a `photo transistor`.... it has a clear window above the silicon chip (almost like an LED has) .... its conductivity increases as received light level increases ..... when the LED shines on the photo transistor, transistor turns on and Vout will be low (depending on how bright the LED is) .... block the light and transistor will turn off and Vout will rise as far as Vin, depending on stray light

Answer (score 1):

That part is a phototransistor. It is one of the types of photodetectors. A phototransistor is similar to the normal BJT but the base region is exposed to the light and when it is exposed, the current will start to flow from Collector to Emitter. Instead of sending current to the base, the base is exposed to the light and when light strikes it activates the transistor.

For more info:- [Phototransistors](https://www.elprocus.com/phototransistor-basics-and-advantages/)

Answer (score 0):

That's a photo transistor which has more gain than a photo diode but more gain variation between devices.

I would choose a narrow angle part for reflective sensor so aiming has more gain ( like a flashlight ) You can also put heat shrink tubing around it to block stray reflected light.  Pulsed Light is easier to detect than steady.

https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/excelitas-technologies/VTT3425LAH/VTT3425LAH-ND/5885878  $2.38 + shipping + tax
 10 deg. The emitter is the longer lead.

Since light power drops inverse squared to distance, x3 with reflection, it will be hard to go far.  An IR remote Rx chip would be more useful then with a heat shrink tube over the emitter LED to make it have laser like aim. Then you can go far (up to 10m) as long as wall reflections don't interfere using a mirror.

The Poulo part is only good for a few mm (QTR-1A)